# Connecting hardware firewall to LAN port still force all traffic through router

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding

Current setup:
All devices connect to a router. The router WAN port is connected to the hardware firewall running pfsense 2.4.4.

However, I am having some port forwarding issues with one device on the network. Rather than do port forwarding for all devices, because the firewall only sees one device (the router), I want the firewall to be able to see all the devices so I can do port forwarding for the one device, but still force all traffic through the router first. (Yes, I know this sounds dumb, but the router allows me to control internet time to the level that pfsense can't)

Due to router firmware I am unable to turn off the DHCP server on it and I can't change the DHCP range.

I have considered plugging the firewall into one of the router's LAN ports and just using the router's DHCP server. But I'm concerned that devices will simply bypass the router's time control settings and still have access to the internet via the firewall.

How can I get the firewall to see at least this one device so I can do port forwarding for just that device?

Comment: Why not configure the port being forwarded by the firewall to also be forwarded by the router to the correct device? Definitely not the recommended way to do it but it sounds like the only option with your setup.

Comment: Can you stop the router doing NAT?  If so can you fix the IP address being given to the end device? If so then I’d do that and the firewall port forwards to the fixed IP address

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator The firewall can only see the router. So if I forward the port it will be forwarded by all traffic/devices and I don't want to do that.

Comment: @Ross I can't stop the router doing NAT. My plan has been that once the firewall can see the device I can give it a static IP address and just forward the ports for that address.

Comment: Forwarding a port through a firewall is nothing more than sending traffic to a next hop device. If you forward the traffic to the router, then it can in turn forward it to the intended target device. From the firewall's point of view, the router *is* the target device, but it doesn't have to be the *last* device in the path.

Answer (score 0):

I believe twisty’s answer is the only way, The firewall port forwards to the router.  The router port forwards to the device.  I don’t fully understand you comment about all devices being forwarded.  As the router is only forwarding a single port to the target device, I’m not sure what you mean by all devices. As it is only this one port which will go to the one device.

Comment: But the firewall can't see the one device.

Comment: Firewall forwards X to the router port 57867.  The router forwards 57867  to the device port Y A packet to the firewall port X will be forwarded to the router's IP port 57867. The router forwards the packet to the device on port Y.  There's no need for the firewall to see the device